# Finding max occurance of a string - Tie case

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects List listOfStudents:
Object:

```
private class Students
{
  private String name;
  private int numberOfTimesComeToSchool;
}
```

I'm trying the find the name of the student that occurs the most number of times and do that I used:

```
listOfStudents.stream().map(Student::getName)collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

If there is no tie then I use

```
Collections.max(collect.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

to determine the name which has occurred the most number of times.

but then it can happen that there is a tie in the name of the students and in this case I want to choose the student name which has come to school the most number of times, i.e. the name of the student which has the highest sum of numberOfTimesComeToSchool out of all of the names.

For example:

```
Student 1: Name: Hello numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 1
Student 2: Name: Hello numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 4
Student 3: Name: Trial numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 2
Student 4: Name: Trial numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 2
Student 5: Name: NeedThis numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 2
Student 6: Name: NeedThis numberOfTimesComeToSchool: 2
```

In this case correct answer would be Hello as the sum of numberOfTimesComeToSchool is 5 while for the rest of the names its only 4, even though all of the names occur the same number of times.

Any help with this would be appricated.

Comment: How would I be able to use that? I never know the student names before hand.

Comment: Call `HashBag.uniqueSet()` and iterate over it. Docs: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem using `.map(Student::getName)`, is that you loose the information about the number of times each student comes to school.

Instead, just use `groupingBy` on the original list so that you get back a `Map<String, List<Student>>`. Then iterate over the entry set of the map, and find the max entry by comparing first the size of the list, and then the sum of `numberOfTimesComeToSchool` in case of a tie.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map =
        listOfStudents.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName));

Optional<String> studentName =
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .max(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, List<Student>>>comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())
                          .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Student::getNumberOfTimesComeToSchool).sum()))
           .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

The type inference is not yet powerful enough, so you have to specify the type parameters in the comparator, which makes it quite hard to read.

Finally you can make it a one-liner by using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
Optional<String> studentName =
    listOfStudents.stream()
                  .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Student::getName),
                                                        m -> m.entrySet()
                                                              .stream()
                                                              .max(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, List<Student>>>comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())
                                                                             .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Student::getNumberOfTimesComeToSchool).sum()))
                                                              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)));
```